# What is the policy for having users that are commercial companies?

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page, advertising

I came across a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4759597/veriloud) which turned out to be a commercial company. Their user profile is a description of their commercial products with the product logo.

Apparently they decided to let their experts go answer questions on SO, in order to get some credibility and free advertising. The answers posted by that user does not however contain any advertising for their products.

The answers are of high technical quality and therefore clearly beneficial for SO. Yet it seems like a sneaky way of advertising.

Also, this particular branch of business (static code analysers) is filled with buggy tools, and a lot of the questions regarding such is about why a tool is giving a strange diagnostic, and the answer is then most often "the tool is broken". So answering questions here would give them a chance to point fingers at the competitors' bugs.

So what is the policy for this? Do we allow commercial companies to lend out their expertise in exchange for the goodwill/free advertising they get for doing so?

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's not a duplicate. This user is not asking questions related to their own product, they are answering general questions about C and MISRA-C asked by other users, none of which is directly related to their own product.

Comment: I don't see a problem with it if their answers aren't spam -- it's no different than anyone else linking to their blog / website in the profile.

Comment: `The answers posted by that user does not however contain any advertising for their products... The answers are of high technical quality and therefore clearly beneficial for SO.` I see no problem here. Technically, we are all advertising ourselves (in one way or another) with our reputation on SO.

Comment: "The answers are of high technical quality and therefore clearly beneficial for SO. Yet it seems like a sneeky way of advertising. " - why? What's sneaky about it? I call it honorable, I wish more companies would do it.

Comment: @Gimby Sneaky as in: "This is clearly a false diagnostic, that tool you are using appears to be broken. Wouldn't you rather use another tool? Cough-cough-nudge-nudge."

Comment: @Lundin errr... that's very far the description you gave in your question, "The answers are of high technical quality and therefore clearly beneficial for SO". Aren't you the sneaky one? ;)